# How to save data as Firestore Timestamp object in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

Just want to save Date as timestamp in Firestore database but it's storing timestamp as number:

```
save() {
    const data = this.transactionForm.value;
    data.type = data.type == 'true' || data.type == true ? true : false;
    data.updated = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    // Date string to timestamp
    data.date =  new Date(data.date.split("-").reverse().join("-")).getTime();
    let id = data.id;
    this.transCollection.doc(id).update(data);
}
```

Comment: I think this is because typescript date is actually displayed in unix time. You can add a | date pipe to your view, to convert it there if that is what you need?

Comment: It's working in view but I want to save a date string as Timestamp in firestore database.

Answer (score 0):

```
  unixToTimestamp() {
    const date = new Date();
    const hours = date.getHours();
    const minutes = date.getMinutes();
    const seconds =  date.getSeconds();
    const day = date.getDate();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date.getFullYear();

    console.log(hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds);
    console.log(day + '/' + month + '/' + year);
  }
```

I tried this out in typescript, and i got the following output:

```
11:25:07
19/11/2018
```

This way you can choose how you want to create your timestamp and save it in firestore

You could also print out month the way you want.

```
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

const month = months[date.getMonth()];
```

This is because date.getMonth() gets index, which is why i use +1 to get a month.

Answer (score 0):

I use timestamp in Firebase and I know it is use to store date in `long` which is number. So I dont know if it is the same in Firestore.